# Should I use bigint or varchar(20) as primary key, performance-wise, for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance

I have 18 character long IDs I get from an API, and I currently store them as `varchar(20)`. They are used as primary and foreign keys. Is it better in my case, to use `bigint` instead of a string type, performance-wise?

Since JavaScript cannot deal with bigints, they are converted by default to string, but I could set columns to be `bigint`, if that will help.

Comment: In common joining/referencing by bigint is more safe than that by varchar. So storing your IDs as a common unique attribute and using bigint synthetic primary (and foreign) key may be more appropriate.

Comment: Why is it more safe? I would say it is slightly more efficient.. with both types you can have missing values if you don’t enforce FKs.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely store as a bigint: this uses 8 bytes, while an 18 character string uses 19 bytes.